# How to find the range (maximum and minimum) of this three-variable function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I want to find the range (maximum and minimum) of this three-variable function
$$f=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=2+\cos \left(x_1-x_2\right)+\sin \left(x_1+x_2-x_3 \right)+\cos \left(x_1+x_3 \right)$$
where all the three variables $-2\pi<x_i<2\pi$.

Is it sufficient to solve of the system of equation
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}=0,$$
or should I consider any other condition as well?

Comment: Do you want to find where all max and min occur? Or do you just want to know the max and min of the function?

Comment: Unless I miss something, I don't think you have to do that.  Since $x_3$ can be set arbitrarily to maximize or minimize the $\sin$ component, we can focus on the two $\cos$ components.  Set $x_2$ to $0$, and then set $x_1$ to either maximize or minimize the $\cos$ components.

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry, my mistake. I corrected the text, the last argument also contains $x_3$

Comment: @Joe I want to know the range of the function ie its global max and min, your second question :)

Comment: Then, using @BrianTung's comment, you can see that the trig functions can each be made equal to 1, or -1, depending on whether you want the max or min.

Comment: In that case, I think you can set $x_2 = -x_3$ and turn this into a two-variable optimization.

Comment: @Joe I edited my function, $x_3$ exists in the third argument as well, then, is BrianTung's comment still applicable? sorry if I ask a lot, my major is not mathematics

Comment: Yes, Brian's comment is still applicable. The maximum is 5 and the minimum is -1.

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you, but I do not understand well since my major is not mathematics. Is this the simplest way? Or, is there a general method for that?

Comment: @BrianTung Very interesting comments that I am having trouble wrapping my brain around.  **If** you have the time, please expand your thoughts into a detailed *answer* to the query, which is what I think your analysis deserves to be.  If you do that, please flag me when done.

Comment: @user2661923, if his comments are hard to understand, it's most likely due to multiple edits in the question (between/after comments).

Comment: @Joe nice of you to say, but in fact, its most likely due to limitations on my math knowledge/experience/intuition/talent, in this area.

Comment: basically, because all three expressions are linearly independent, there is a transformation that can transform the expression into $2+\cos x +\sin y + \cos z$

Comment: I admit my "set $x_2 = -x_3$" comment was a little cryptic; it took advantage of a symmetry in the expressions.  I explain more fully in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Vasya's comment, we observe that the three expressions

$$
x_1-x_2 \\
x_1+x_2-x_3 \\
x_1+x_3
$$

are linearly independent, so we can solve (for example)

\begin{align}
x_1-x_2 \phantom{{}+x_3} & = 0 \\
x_1+x_2-x_3 & = \frac\pi2 \\
x_1\phantom{{}+x_2}+x_3 & = 0
\end{align}

to yield $x_1 = x_2 = \pi/6, x_3 = -\pi/6$ to get the maximum of $5$.  A similar approach yields the minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much, this argument works in this case where one of the functions is $\sin$. What would happen if all the functions were $\cos$? Then, is it sufficient to solve the mentioned equation?

Comment: @Phys96: Sure.  You would set the three expressions all to $0$ for the maximum, for example.  That has the trivial solution $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$.  As Vasya pointed out in the comments, you can set each of the three expressions independently to whatever values you want.

Comment: @Phys96: Correct.

Comment: +1 nice........